# How do i check if a variable is a specific number in JS

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to make a simple clicker game (im pretty new to coding in javascript) but the player can buy things even if they dont have enough, so i tried to do this

```
function clickpowup() {
    if(click += 50) {
        clickpower += 5;
        click += -50;
    }
    if(click !== 50) {
       alert("Not enough cookies")
         
 }
```

This is how my variables are laid out above the text

```
var click = 0;
var clickpower=1;
```

Comment: Can you try to explain what you are trying to achieve with your code.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Generally when talking about code, its useful to talk in terms of _behaviour_. Ideally we'd like to know what the _intended behaviour_ is (what you would like your code to do), and what it _actually does_.

Comment: Since you are"someone "new to coding in javascript", I suggest that you learn about and use the "alert" and "console.log" statements. They can help you display variable values. They are also good debugging tools.

Answer (score 1):

```
function clickpowup() {
if(click += 50) { ///here the code is wrong? if(click <= 50) you want?
    clickpower += 5;
    click += -50;
}
if(click !== 50) {
   alert("Not enough cookies")
 }
```

The if the condition seems wrong. `if(click <= 50)` are you looking for something like this?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your code right and understanding it... did you mean += to be "greater than or equal to?" If so, that's >= not +=. Also `if (click !== 50)` would mean "if click is not 50." 51 is not 50, but is "enough cookies" so that should be `if (click <= 50)`, right?

Answer (score 0):

The if condition you have coded is not correct(if(click += 50)).The if condition should return either true or false. It cannot interpret the output of this addition operation.

**END NOTE:**

Please try to explain your code in a better way